# Is it consistent with ZFC(A) for the Hartogs number of a proper class to be $\aleph_0$?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

I'm specifically assuming that we have replacement instead of collection; collection breaks things (because then there is a set that contains a map from $n$ to $C$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$, and you can look within that set to get an injection from an infinite subset of $C$ to some infinite set, so $\aleph(C)$ couldn't have been $\aleph_0$.

The construction that seems to work in ZFCA is to take a model of ZFA with infinitely many atoms and then take the direct limit of $L(A_n)$, where $A_n$ is the set of the first $n$ atoms. This seems to be a model of ZFCA, because every set belongs to $L(A_n)$ for some $n$ and therefore inherits a well-ordering from that (as $L(A_n)$ still has a global choice function definable from parameters).

I can't see how replacement fails where collection did, because I can't think any $\varphi$ such that $\forall n\exists!x\varphi(n,x)$ and $\varphi(n,x)$ implies that $x$ is an injection from $n$ into the class of atoms, or anything else that would cause the union of all such $x$s to not fit into any $L(A_n)$.

This of course cannot be extended to a model of GBCA, because the existence of a proper class that is smaller than the universe prevents the existence of a global choice function.

If the construction works and can be extended to ZFC, it does prove that the Hartogs number of classes is interesting in NBG even with the axiom of choice (NBG being conservative over ZFC).

Comment: Are you talking about a version of ZFCA where the collection of atoms do not need to form a set?

Comment: Conservativity of GBC over ZFC specifically refers to statements about sets -- GBC can prove things about proper classes that ZFC can't, so your last sentence seems dubious to me.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1619246/622

Comment: @JamesHanson Yep

Comment: @AlecRhea Does that include proper classes definable from set parameters?

Comment: For another possible reference, following Jech's book "the axiom of choice" in chapter 9 problem 3 and 4 they construct models of ZFCA with infinitely many atoms but every set contains only finitely many atoms in its transitive closure by generalizing permutation models whose permutations are permutations over a proper class, in such models the Hartogs number of the class of atoms is $\aleph_0$

Comment: @Holo I'd like to add that permutation is not needed for getting a proper class with  Hartogs number $\aleph_0$. Taking sets with finite kernels will do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. If you start with infinitely many urelements and then take the sets whose kernel is finite (the kernel of a set is the set of urelements in its transitive closure), the resultant inner model will satisfy Replacement. A more generalized argument is included in my dissertation (https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.14274, Theorem 26).

Let ZFU$_\text{R}$ denote ZF set theory with urelements axiomatized with Replacement. In general, given a model $U$ of ZFU$_R$ an ideal $\mathcal{I}$ of the class of all urelements that contains every urelement singleton, the inner model $U^\mathcal{I}$, which contains all urelements and sets whose kernel is in $\mathcal{I}$, is a model of ZFU$_R$ also. And $U^\mathcal{I}$ satisfies AC if $U$ does. So in the case of ZFCU$_\text{R}$, the Hartogs number of a proper class can be any infinite cardinal.

For ZFCU$_\text{R}$ + Collection, the Hartogs number of a proper class cannot be any limit cardinal by the argument you have given. But this is the only constraint: for every successor infinite cardinal $\kappa^+$, there can be models of ZFCU$_\text{R}$ + Collection where the Hartogs number of the class of urelements is $\kappa^+$. This follows from Lemma 21 and Theorem 26 in my dissertation.

The result for ZFCU$_\text{R}$ **can** be extended to GBU$_\text{R}$ (in fact, KMU$_\text{R}$) with a global choice function. This is due to Felgner (see Theorem 108 in my dissertation). In class theory with urelements, it is important to distinguish different versions of second-order AC. For example, the existence of a global choice function doesn’t imply the universe can be well-ordered, as shown in Felgner’s model.

However, it is not known, for example, if KMU$_\text{R}$ + Collection + Global Choice (not Global Well-Ordering) is consistent with a proper class with Hartogs number, say, $\aleph_1$.

Comment: I think in your dissertation you also have the case of a proper class with Hartog number $\aleph_1$, and indeed this example has the urelement theory with collection and not merely replacement. Isn't it true that one can arrange such a situation with any given uncountable cardinal $\kappa$? (Or at least successor cardinals?) Can we have such classes for more than one $\kappa$ at a time, or perhaps even all $\kappa$?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I've edited my answer to address your comment.

Comment: Oh, cool! So global choice is weaker than limitation of size. This raises the question of whether the Hartogs number of a proper class can be $\aleph_1$ even without urelements.

Comment: $\aleph_0$ is out because replacement implies collection in the absence of a proper class of urelements.

Comment: Oh, that's a shame. So there's no model of this in ZF. Well, that answers all my questions on the topic thoroughly: the class of atoms can have any Hartogs number that's an infinite successor cardinal, and with replacement instead of collection it can also be an infinite limit cardinal. I'm glad to see someone else has asked the question.

Comment: @NoLongerBreathedIn Sorry, my previous comment was not correct and I deleted it. So the situation is this.  When a proper class of urelements is allowed, Global Choice is weaker than Global Well-Ordering, which is in turn weaker than Limitation of Size (they are equivalent when there is only a set of urelements). With only a set of urelements and **assuming AC for sets** , no proper class can have a Hartog number because every ordinal injects into it by a standard ZFC argument as in here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2109874/do-there-exist-proper-classes-that-arent-too-big.

Comment: OK, so that leaves the question of Hartogs numbers of proper classes in ZF unclear. Oh well.

Comment: @NoLongerBreathedIn I recently asked Asaf this question. Asaf told me that using class forcing and symmetric models we can basically make a proper class have any infinite Hartogs number.

Comment: @NoLongerBreathedIn BTW, would you consider accepting my answer?